# Nested routes for comments without using resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am in the process of building a forum and the threads are setup and viewing no problem. While in the process of trying to create the comments within a thread, I seem to be confused with how to setup the routes. Normally I know people have nested routes:

```
resources :threads do
  resources :comments
end
```

Though the difference is my routes do not use the resources method as I have them setup individually:

```
get '/thread' => 'threads#discussion'
post '/create_thread' => 'threads#create'
get '/create_thread' => 'threads#new', :as => :new_thread
get '/threads/:id' => 'threads#show', :as => :thread_show
get 'threads/edit/:id' => 'threads#edit', :as => :edit_thread
put '/threads/edit/:id' => 'threads#update', :as => :update_thread
delete 'threads/:id' => 'threads#destroy'
```

***Thread/threads replaced the actual location name***

Is there a way for me to place nested routes for the comments within each thread? I've give the proper associations for each model (Users, Threads, Comments) and added the user_id, thread_id to the Comments model.

If you have any knowledge on the correct way to setup the routes for the comments or know of an article, please list it here.

Thank you so much!

**EDIT**

The comments will be placed directly onto the thread page and not a new page.

Joe

Comment: Use resourceful routes. There's no reason not to, and it will save you a lot of headaches like this.

Comment: I just was not sure if resourceful routes were similar to scaffold. It's an option but always the best way to go?

Comment: There are times when you may need to manually define a route with e.g. `get` in addition to your resourceful routes, but all of the routes you posted correspond directly to routes that `resources` would automatically define for you, so it's absolutely the best way to go in your case.

Comment: Okay, thank you - If you wanted to post in the answer, I will give you the points. Thanks again.

Comment: Side note, it is not possible to user the :as with resourceful routes, is it?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible. Have you read the Rails Guide on routing? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers

Comment: Will check there, perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do nested routes "manually" like so:

```
get '/threads/:thread_id/comments/new' => 'comments#new'
get '/threads/:thread_id/comments/:id' => 'comments#show'
```

And CommentsController's `new` action can do something like:

```
def new
  @thread = Thread.find(params[:thread_id])
  @comment = @thread.comments.build
end
```

However, I strongly agree with [Jordan's advice above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711135/nested-routes-for-comments-with-our-using-resources#comment51360588_31711135); your routes are a bit messy, not fully RESTful, and would be much easier to express via resourceful routing.